# Nginx not rendering .json URLs - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nginx

I have a Rails 4 application with nginx 1.4.4 and I'm having issues trying to access JSON routes.

I'm trying to access the following route:

```
http://www.example.com/products/106.json
```

Which produces a 404 / Not found in my nginx server. However, in my development server it works correctly (a Thin server), it displays the product as JSON.

I have already added the application/json       json; line to the mime.types config file.

What else should I look in order to fix this? I can provide more information if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried without .json on the url and setting the request header as json?

Comment: Do you see any 404 errors in production.log? I think no. Seems like you incorrectly configure nginx and it doesn't proxy request to your application.

Comment: @arieljuod, it worked! I'll just leave it like this for now. I'm still curious about what needs to be configured in ngnix in order to access the .json routes.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your nginx config, but it looks like it's trying to serve a json file itself instead of passing the request to tour Rails app